# Big Data project requirements using twitter streams

Tags: twitter, streaming, cloudera

I am currently trying to break into Data engineering and I figured the best way to do this was to get a basic understanding of the Hadoop stack(played around with Cloudera quickstart VM/went through tutorial) and then try to build my own project. I want to build a data pipeline that ingests twitter data, store it in HDFS or HBASE, and then run some sort of analytics on the stored data. I would also prefer that I use real time streaming data, not historical/batch data. My data flow would look like this:

```
Twitter Stream API --> Flume --> HDFS --> Spark/MapReduce --> Some DB
```

Does this look like a good way to bring in my data and analyze it?
Also, how would you guys recommend I host/store all this?
Would it be better to have one instance on AWS ec2 for hadoop to run on? or should I run it all in a local vm on my desktop?

I plan to have only one node cluster to start.

Comment: You don't need Hadoop at all. Your  previous questions indicate that you have Spark, so just read from Twitter with it. http://bahir.apache.org/docs/spark/current/spark-streaming-twitter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Spark Streaming can read from Twitter, and in CDH, I believe that is the streaming framework of choice.

Your pipeline is reasonable, though I might suggest using Apache NiFi (which is in the Hortonworks HDF distribution), or Streamsets, which is installable in CDH easily, from what I understand.

Note, these are running completely independently of Hadoop. Hint: Docker works great with them. HDFS and YARN are really the only complex components that I would rely on a pre-configured VM for.

Both Nifi and Streamsets give you a drop and drop UI for hooking Twitter to HDFS and "other DB".

Flume can work, and one pipeline is easy, but it just hasn't matured at the level of the other streaming platforms. Personally, I like a Logstash -> Kafka -> Spark Streaming  pipeline better, for example because Logstash configuration files are nicer to work with (Twitter plugin builtin). And Kafka works with a bunch of tools.

You could also try out Kafka with Kafka Connect, or use Apache Flink for the whole pipeline.

Primary takeaway, you can bypass Hadoop here, or at least have something like this

```
Twitter > Streaming Framework > HDFS 
              ..       > Other DB
              ...      > Spark
```

Regarding running locally or not, as long as you are fine with paying for idle hours on a cloud provider, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Wouldn't it be expense to run on aws though? I know have the options between an ec2 instance or just using EMR, but would this work well just on a local vm and have it run whenever I have my vm running?

Comment: Depends how long you want to have it running... If you're just learning and have reasonable memory (more than 8GB) and at least 20GB disk space, then a VM is fine. Though, you've installed Spark from homebrew, right? You can stream files straight to local disk, not HDFS

Comment: Also AWS is not the only Hadoop Cloud provider. Not sure if it's the cheapest

Comment: I know but it's one of the biggest and want more experience using aws. I will just setup a hadoop dist on a vm then! Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, one of the main reasons for wanting to use hadoop is so I can use HDFS(get experience with it) and also use Hive for some queries of my data. Also, I forgot to ask this question, but would I just stream data/files into my own computer's disk or the VM's disk?

Comment: Fair enough. And you would write to HDFS within the VM. Or, you can mount your local filesystem into the VM and stream to it local filesystem, depending on the tool you use.